# How to install python without idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I'm using Archlinux and I find I don't need Idle when I'm coding Python.

Here is part of the default PKGBUILD file:

```
    ./configure --prefix=/usr \
                --enable-shared \
                --with-threads \
                --with-computed-gotos \
                --enable-ipv6 \
                --with-valgrind \
                --with-system-expat \
                --with-dbmliborder=gdbm:ndbm \
                --with-system-ffi

     ln -sf idle3     "${pkgdir}"/usr/bin/idle
```

Can I build python without installing Idle?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this build idle?

Comment: @LutzHorn PKGBUILD only has ``ln -sf idle3 "{pkgdir}"/usr/bin/idle``. Maybe build it by default?

Comment: IDLE is a set of Python scripts which occupy less than 1MB. 'Tis probably easiest to remove them after install than tweak autoconf output (or just not run idle, unless you are on a very disk-limited machine).

Comment: @jasonz You may want to delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it's not possible to install Python without Idle.  There are no config switches or other methods to exclude it.  Idle can be an extremely valuable tool.  I would risk saying that although you don't see a need for it today, it may come in handy in the future.